# Android Studio Setup- Displaying gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting Gradle sync error after installing the Android Studio.
It is displaying followinng errors :
 ***Gradle 'Second' project refresh failed 

   Error:Artifact 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2:gradle.jar' not found.***

Please help me.

Snapshot :
[image]

Comment: Include your root level build.gradle file too.

Comment: Can you post all gradle file you have. And i suggest you to use new gradle with com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+

Comment: @pyus13 - I have included that also.